# jquery jtable inserting/updating record with apostrophe

Tags: php, jquery, sql, jtable

I have jtable working perfectly fine with adding/editing/removing records however I cant insert/update a record that contains an apostrophe ! Someone please help!

Below is a snapshot fo my code

> Blockquote //Updating a record (updateAction)

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE teg_priority SET CustomerName = '" . $_POST["CustomerName"] . "', Service_Manager = '" . $_POST["Service_Manager"]. "', NGM = '" . $_POST["NGM"] . "', Tag = '" . $_POST["Tag"] . "', CBS = '" . $_POST["CBS"]. "' WHERE CIDN = " . $_POST["CIDN"] . ";");

```
    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use addslashes on the variables before putting them in the query.

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE teg_priority SET CustomerName = '" . addslashes($_POST["CustomerName"]) . "', Service_Manager = '" . addslashes($_POST["Service_Manager"]). "', NGM = '" . addslashes($_POST["NGM"]) . "', Tag = '" . addslashes($_POST["Tag"]) . "', CBS = '" . addslashes($_POST["CBS"]). "' WHERE CIDN = " .addslashes( $_POST["CIDN"]) . ";");
```